# shell script exit status 127

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh

I have just stated working on an application created with PHP and C language, there is a lot of shell script. The PHP code call a shell script to execute this line

```
ssh -x $user@$host '. /sh/pre.sh '"$user"' PRE;  $EXE/cmd.com'" $fi $fi1 $fi2"
```

the file `pre.sh` contail all envirement variable.

when I run this command from the terminal it works. but when I call it from the PHP code it return 127. what's the problem ?

I changed $EXE/cmd.com with /usr/exe/cmd.com and it works, I think `. /sh/pre.sh` it's used to export all envirement variabled, because the value of `$EXE` is inside `pre.sh`

Another question, I didn't worked with shell script before, so this command execute cmd.com   on the current server or on the server $host ?

Comment: 127 usually means the shell can't find the command. In this case, it's unclear whether the remote shell can't find `$EXE/cmd.com` (with `$EXE` being expanded remotely) or whether it does not understand `.` or whether the `.` utility can't find `/sh/pre.sh`.

Comment: I changed $EXE/cmd.com with /usr/exe/cmd.com and it works

Comment: Hello NarutoUzumaki. Regarding your second question, please go to the man-page for `ssh`. The first line in the page tells you: "ssh (SSH client) is a program for logging into a remote machine and for executing commands on a remote machine."

Comment: @Chibine thanks for your answer, but what should I do exactly ?